# Plus signs running across edit boxes, etc

Tags: keyboard

I often have endless pluses (+) run across any place where characters can be entered - e.g. edit boxes, the url bar, the window where a password is entered. I can't delete them or stop them. It's gotten so bad that I have to shut my laptop down for many hours in order to even enter my Ubuntu account on the laptop.

Is there a way to get rid of this?

Comment: Are you using an external keyboard?

Comment: No. But I am using an external mouse.

Comment: It sounds like you have a stuck key on your laptop keyboard.

Comment: If this is the case, how do I unstick it?

Comment: Well, try fiddling with the plus key?

Comment: Ok, thanks. I fiddled with it. I won't know if this worked until the pluses start up again.

Comment: I remembered something else. Sometimes (when the plus phenomenon is happening) a small window filled with pluses appears in the lower right-hand corner of my screen. So I doubt it has anything to do with the plus key.

Comment: It would be useful to have a screen shot of that (the small window in the corner).

Comment: When in Nautilus (and some other programs) a search box appears in the lower-right when you start typing in the window. You can open Nautilus and try it for yourself. If your plus key started "typing" itself, it would bring up that little text window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a mechanical problem, but if you can make it past the login textbox without the pluses happening it wouldn't hurt to change this field in System Settings:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, Klukva Khan. I unchecked the 'key presses repeat when key is held down'.